# Question on DBLink for 2 databases oracle

Tags: database, oracle, dblink

I have a server with 2 databases: dbtest and checkdb.
I need that user user_b of dbtest can made a select on a table of other database.
How i have to set the dblink?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267218/how-to-create-a-db-link-between-two-oracle-instances

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your script run

```
alter session set global_names=false;
```

then whenever you need to fetch data from checkdb you add the link as a suffix. don't know exactly how your dbs are defined but something like

user_b is on dbtest

```
select * from table_name@dblink 
#might be that dblink is not the exact name.
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Connected as user in one of those databases, create a database link to another database *following the syntax* (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793). It hasn't changed for ages, I suppose.

For example:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_scott     -- database link name
  2    connect to scott                 -- you're connecting to this user (scott) ...
  3    identified by tiger              -- ... which is identified by this password (tiger)
  4    using 'db11g:1521/orcl';         -- using clause has a database server (db11g):port (1521)/service name (orcl)

Database link created.

SQL> -- Testing; it has to return a row
SQL> select * From dual@dbl_scott; 

D
-
X

SQL>
```

The `USING` clause could be *shortened* by putting target database alias (the one written in `TNSNAMES.ORA` file on your database server). If you don't have access to that file (as you aren't a DBA), then the above option works OK.

Note that - even if you use invalid settings - database link might be created, but it won't work. For example:

```
SQL> drop database link dbl_scott;

Database link dropped.

SQL> create database link dbl_scott
  2    connect to xyzalksfjlaskfj
  3    identified by abc
  4    using '9809803242';

Database link created.

SQL> select * from dual@dbl_scott;
select * from dual@dbl_scott
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SQL>
```

Therefore, be careful.