# Stored Procedure to check matching records in two tables of two different databases PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a task to create a stored procedure in Oracle DB. Given two different databases DB1 with  student_lookup table  and DB2 with student_master table  . The SP needs to check if DB2.student_master's record  exists in DB1.student_lookup table.

1. If the record exists in DB1 then don't anything
2. If the record doesn't exists in DB1 then add from DB2
3. If the record is in DB1 but not DB2 then update that record and set partition_key column to 1.

Any help will be appreciated. I am completely new to Oracle DBA.

Comment: [How to create a DB link between two oracle instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267218/how-to-create-a-db-link-between-two-oracle-instances)

Comment: [Oracle “Partition By” Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561836/oracle-partition-by-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's two users using:

```
MERGE INTO db1.student_lookup a 
USING 
(select * from db2.student_mater) b 
ON (
a.id = b.id 
AND <others join column>
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.partition_key = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (<a.column>)
VALUES (<b.column>)
```

If it's two db:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_DB1_DB2
  CONNECT TO DB2 IDENTIFIED BY <ENTER USER PASSWORD HERE>
  USING '<FROM tnsnames>'


MERGE INTO db1.student_lookup a 
USING 
(select * from "student_mater"@"DBLINK_DB1_DB2") b 
ON (
a.id = b.id 
AND <others join column>
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.partition_key = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (<a.column>)
VALUES (<b.column>)
```

If you neen SP simple megre into your SP.

Comment: Thank you! My lead suggested to use for loop in order to achieve a result. I like your approach better.

Comment: You are welcome! Merge is very helpful and powerful statement. And very fast.