# Compare two oracle database tables and it values in effective way

Tags: oracle, data-comparison

Two oracle database like `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB`. Both are mirror database. Each database has 20 tables.  `DatabaseA` is pointing to old approach Spring batch and It is same as production. Spring batch was modified for design problem. New Spring batch application is pointing to `DatabaseB`.

if I ran the same file both spring batch approaches, Both database should have same entries in table.

I need to compare all the table values are same in both approaches.

Is there any way to compare? Any tool to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 tables are not much, you can write a procedure for that case.
If there are actually two databases, you must first set up a [DB link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267218/how-to-create-a-db-link-between-two-oracle-instances) between the databases.

to compare you can use a minus operator

```
select *
from(
      ( select * from tab1
         minus
        select * from tab2
      )
      union all
      ( select * from tab2
         minus
        select * from tab1
      )
)
```

Comment: I don't have privileges to create Link. Could you provide any other possible way.?

Comment: @vigneshwaranm you can ask a dba to create one, I don't see any security concerns  why i should not create one if you need to comlet that task. otherwise you can do a schema export on one database and import the schema under a second user on the other database