# How to update oracle table with another oracle table in python

Tags: python, database, oracle

I want to Migrate data from an oracle database to another oracle database using python

```py
# first database connection 
con1 = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, host/service)
cursor1 = con1.cursor()    

# second database connection 
con2 = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, host/service)
cursor2 = con1.cursor()                                  
sql = "insert into db2.table select * from db2.table"
```

Comment: Rather, using a `Create Table AS` statement would run faster after having created a DB link.

Comment: The table exists in both databases already

Comment: you can still consider the suggestion, if the target one is totally empty.

Comment: And if not empty, the [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html) statement may be more appropriate than INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this.

## 1. DB link

You want to

```sql
TRUNCATE db2.tbl;

INSERT INTO db2.tbl  SELECT *  FROM db1.tbl;
```

You don't need a pair of cursors,
a pair of open DB connections, to do that.
A single connection to db2 suffices.
What you *do* need is a [DB link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm),
so that db2 queries enjoy access to db1 tables.
The syntax is:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_name
    CONNECT TO remote_user_name IDENTIFIED BY password
    USING 'remote_database_name/connection_string';
```

So if you called it `link_db1`,
you would transfer data with

```
INSERT INTO tbl  SELECT *  FROM link_db1.tbl;
```

After your client sends the command to db2, the client is out of the picture.
There could be a million result rows, and they all flow directly
from the db1 server to the db2 server.
The client doesn't touch a single row.
If client suffers from low network bandwidth,
that won't impact the throughput of copying lots of row data.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/ds_concepts002.htm

[How to create a DB link between two oracle instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267218/how-to-create-a-db-link-between-two-oracle-instances)

---

## 2. in-memory copy

You *can* create a pair of connections if you want, one to each database.

Download the rows from one, and insert them via the other connection.

You can do it in a single batch if the client has sufficient memory,
or you might prefer to do batches of a few thousand rows at a time.
(Don't do a single row at a time, as it will be latency dominated -- the
throughput will be disappointingly low.)
Network bandwidth available to the client will play a big role
in how quickly the rows can be copied.

The [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) / [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) functions offer *one* way to accomplish the copying.

This is the less attractive option.
Prefer using a DB link, if feasible.

Comment: Some notes: If option 2 is used (despite being less efficient), make sure to tune `arraysize` when fetching, and use `executemany()` to do the insert in batches.  Also, its time to upgrade to the new version of cx_Oracle (now called python-oracled), see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  The new 'Thin' mode will almost certainly be faster for this kind of  data transfer.