# Update mysql field value based on another field value

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL databases the first one has one table `t1` that has three fields `id`, `t2id`, `f` and the second one has table `t2` that has two fields `id`, `f`
the `t1.t2id` should have the same value as `t2.id` where `t1.f` = `t2.f`, however the value of `t2.id` is changing every day.

What I want to achieve is that whenever the value of `t2.id` is changed the value of `t1.t2id` will be updated as well, is that possible using a procedure?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to use a [**Trigger**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) after the INSERT or the UPDATE on the table `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented, you can use `TRIGGER`s ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)).

You would probably want two triggers, one upon insertion and one upon update.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_t1 AFTER INSERT ON t2
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO t1
       (t2id, f)
       VALUES
       (NEW.id, NEW.f);
   END //

   CREATE TRIGGER insert_t1 AFTER UPDATE ON t2
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       UPDATE t1
       SET 
           f = NEW.f
       WHERE 
           t2id = NEW.id;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

*Edit*:
To adjust for the multiple databases, you need to qualify them, assuming the user has permissions to both databases (I'm assuming they're on the same host).

So rather than: `CREATE TRIGGER insert_t1 AFTER INSERT ON t2....` you would do `CREATE TRIGGER db1.insert_t1 AFTER INSERT ON db2.t2...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned in my question the two tables are related to two different databases so would the triggers work in this case?

Comment: Updated my answer, qualification seems to be supported in MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832759/creating-trigger-across-different-databases